# Как использовать данные о размерах кэшей процессора для ускорения программы?

Tags: c++, ассемблер, x86-64, x86

У каждого процессора есть кэш различных уровней и размеров.

1. Есть ли смысл писать программу таким образом, что б абсолютно все используемые массивы, переменные и т.п. в оперативной памяти занимали 
   строго последовательные адреса? Т.е. например: начальный адрес `90870000`, конечный `90880000`. Есть смысл что б этом промежутке были исключительно данные конкретной программы?
2. Как влияет на скорость программы соотношение размера кэшей и используемого размера оперативной памяти?
3. Есть ли смысл обработку данных во много раз больших размера кэшей проводить блоками? Каждый блок меньше размера кэша.
4. В ассемблере есть инструкции по записи в оперативную память без использования кэша. Какой в этом смысл?
5. Какую из двух инструкций и в каких случаях использовать для возврата 128 бит результата обработки обратно в память?

   ```
        movdqu [ebx],xmm0
        movntps [ebx],xmm0//без использования кэша
   ```

Правильно я понимаю, что если эти 128 бит больше не нужны для обратотки, то лучше movntps? Это быстрее?

6. Предположим есть чернобелое bmp изображение 1024*1024.
   Перенесем все его пиксели в:

   ```
       unsigned __int8 *src_img
       src_img = new unsigned __int8[1024*1024];//каждый байт это значение одного пикселя от 0 до 255
   ```

Допустим есть два варианта алгоритма:
1) копируем в xmm0 128 бит из src_img, что-то делаем в xmm регистрах и возвращаем измененные 128бит обратно по тому же адресу в оперативную память. Самое важное эти 128 бит выбираются от начала src_img последовательно до конца.
2) Делаем тоже самое, но 128 бит выбираются не последовательно,а из разных мест src_img
1-й вариант будет быстрее или нет? Или формулируя по другому: первоначально программа берет данные из: movdqu xmm0,[ebx]. Имеет различие для быстродействия насколько далеко от первоначального адреса программа берет следующие 128 бит?

Изучаю данные вопросы в контексте вот этой задачи:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747393/prewitt-edge-detection-algorithm-using-x86-mmx-simd

Comment: Задача не практическая, но академическая стоит?

Comment: учебная, изучаю все аспекты, которые позволят предельно ускорить алгоритм на конкретном процессоре

Comment: Это надо еще постараться найти такую задачу при которой бы требовались интенсивные вычисления на одном и том же блоке данных небольшого размера. Думаю про кеш достаточно знать что он есть, и стараться часто используемые переменные держать рядом (а они обычно и так рядом, т.к. в стеке лежат, а стек самая нагруженная область обычно). И не забывайте, что в системах с вытесняющей многозадачностью процессор в любой момент отдадут другому процессу и он ваш кеш забьет. Итого: при правильном использовании кеша конечно скорость может сильно вырасти, но круг подходящих задач очень узок

Comment: добавил пару более конкретных вопросов

Comment: По поводу 5: Вы тут смешали понятия кэширование и выравнивание. `movdqu` - перемещает по **невыровненому** адресу, `movdqa` - по **выровненному**, а `movntps` - перемещает по **выровненному** адресу **мимо кэша**. Выравнивание - это еще один бонус для оптимизации при работе с `xmm`. Команды типа `movntps` (с non-temporal hint) конечно выполняются быстрее, если Вы после них не читаете по этим же адресам.

Comment: На практике все немного сложнее, поскольку используется иерархия кэшей. Обычно существует 2 L1 кэша (один для команд, другой для данных). Типичный размер L1 data 32Kbyte (размер линии 32 или 64 байта = 256/512 бит). L1 кэш (конечно когерентен) тесно  связан с одним ядром. L2 кэш (типично 1-2 Mbyte) разделяется парой (или четверкой) ядер (т.е. локален для кластера) и он уже общий для данных и инструкций. Далее могут быть кэши L3 и L4 (иногда это просто быстрый буфер между L2 и памятью, размером не менее суммы всех L2). Скорость доступа к L1 и L2 может отличаться на порядок.

Comment: И еще. Обмен данными между кэшами разных уровней и кэшем и памятью всегда происходит целыми линиями кэша (в так называемом burst режиме, т.е. в одном такте передают адрес, в остальных последовательно данные кэш линии)

Comment: Можно наверное выделить общий принцип для оптимизаций с кэшем (не учитывая внешних факторов): объем информации, который будет доступен в кэше не должен превышать его размер, т.е., можно гарантировать, что алгоритм будет работать с памятью на скорости кэша, если объем данных этого алгоритма помещается в этот кэш. Если нет возможности разместить весь объем данных в кэше, то для лучшей производительности алгоритма, следует раздробить его по итерациям, где объем данных каждой из таких итераций должен вмещаться в кэш. Насчет кооперации кэшей между ядрами - уже писал, это тоже актуально.

Comment: То, что есть в интернете в основном касается темы выравнивания при написании кода на C++. Я не могу понять вот что.
movq xmm1,[ebx]
movq xmm1,[ebx+1]
Что, эти две команды не одинаково быстро выполняются? Есть адреса по которым команды перемещения в регистры и обратно выполняются быстро и адреса по которым медленно?

Comment: "Есть адреса по которым команды перемещения в регистры и обратно выполняются быстро и адреса по которым медленно?" -- [конечно](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Есть смысл что б этом промежутке были исключительно данные конкретной программы?

Это зависит от программы. Если она оч. часто обращается к этим переменным, то да, конечно - размещение всех ее данных в блоке, который занимает минимальное к-во кеш-линий, ускорит эти операции.

Обычно не говорят о размещении всех данных в одной кеш-линии. На практике это невозможно. Обычно говорят о "кратном рамере" блока данных.

> Как влияет на скорость программы соотношение размера кэшей и используемого размера оперативной памяти?

Особой разницы с первым вопросом не вижу. Если у Вас программа оптимизирована под загрузку кеша, и учитывает его размер, конечно, она будет быстрее работать на железе с большим кешем. Надеюсь, Вы так же вкурсе, что кеши есть разных уровней (level1, level2, level3, кеш данных, кеш инструкций), их размеры могут отличаться, и скорость доступа к ним, естественно, тоже разная, т.е. поле для оптимизаций - обширное настолько, насколько Вам хватит терпения перебирать различное железо для экспериментов и фантазии на реализацию алгоритмов.

> Есть ли смысл обработку данных во много раз больших размера кэшей проводить блоками? Каждый блок меньше размера кэша.

Нет. Есть смысл распараллелить эту обработку между ядрами таким образом, чтобы у каждого ядра эти порции данных, по возможности, не пересекались. Вот тут кратность размера обрабатываемого блока данных имеет большое значение. Порции следует разделить так, чтобы кеш-линии одного ядра не пересекались с кеш-линиями другого.

> В ассемблере есть инструкции по записи в оперативную память без использования кэша. Какой в этом смысл?

Смысл в том, чтобы не делать лишнюю работу: если Вам нужно только переместить блок данных, и Вы не обращаетесь к нему для каких-то рассчетов, то и в кеш его нет необходимости загружать.

> Имеет различие для быстродействия насколько далеко от первоначального адреса программа берет следующие 128 бит?

Нет, не должно. На 64битных кеш-линиях, по крайней мере, последовательное чтение 128битных значений в непараллельной программе выгоды не дает. В этом случае определяющим будет размер кеша и параллелизм между ядрами (кооперация кэшей). Ждите или ищите 256битных кеш линий, по крайней мере :)

Comment: >> `Есть ли смысл обработку данных во много раз больших размера кэшей проводить блоками? Каждый блок меньше размера кэша.` << — на самом деле есть, но круг практических задач, где это поможет несколько ограничен... и в любом случае на практике стоит расчехлить свой прафайлер...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, сможете привести пример, где это даст выигрыш?

Comment: гм... не могу ничего невырожденного придумать, где выигрыш от обработки блоками был бы связан именно с размером кеша... при умножении матриц, например, можно получить выигрыш перемножая блоки равные по ширине/высоте размеру линейки, но это по сути другое... в качестве эзотерического примера, можно привести что-то такое: «100 раз сложить все элементы массива», в наивной реализации он явно не эффективен, но при делении всего массива на блоки равные размеру кеша он немного ускорится...

Comment: Возможно я не прав и действительно всегда можно изменить весь алгоритм вместо того чтобы делить данные на блоки влезающие в кеш... но без строгого доказательства я бы это утверждать не взялся бы...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, кэш-линия загружается при первом же обращении по любому адресу.  Если Вы пройдетесь по произвольному массиву, от его начала до конца (читая его по ходу), он целиком будет пропущен через кэш. Нет ни какой разницы, какими блоками вы пройдете этот массив. Можно сделать только хуже, если алгоритм дробления этого массива сам залезет в кэш. В таком случае Вы получите плохие результаты, т.к. какое-то время будет потрачено на кэширование локальных переменных. Более подробно по кешам можно почитать в вики: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache (этот вариант более детализирован, чем русский)

Comment: разница появляется если идти по столбцам матрицы...

Comment: Эта разница может быть только в худшую сторону: если идти по столбцам матрицы, то загружая кэш-линию, Вы используете только первый ее элемент (условно). Если кэш не вмещает всю матрицу, то остаток каждой вытесненной кэш-линии вы прочитали впустую, т.е. потеряли время. И еще потратите время на ее повторные загрузки в кэш. Читать матрицу по столбцам - дороже, чем последовательно пройтись по массиву.

Comment: Об этом я и говорю, если обрабатывать по два/четыре столбца за раз, то это несколько улучшит ситуацию... т.е. при перемножении матрицы на каждой итерации фактически обрабатываются блоками 2x2 (для `int64_t`)... но именно этот приём ни как не связан с общим размером кеша...

Comment: Во первых, чтобы обработать параллельно несколько столбцов матрицы, нужно, чтобы число ее строк было по крайней мере меньше либо равно числу кэш-линий. Во вторых, алгоритм вытеснения кэш-линий ничего не знает о Ваших замыслах (Replacement policies), поэтому, скорее всего просто не позволит Вам вытеснить весь кэш одним массивом, т.е. обязательно будут потери. Ну и в третьих, даже при таком чудесном стечении обстоятельств, разница будет все в том же дроблении матрицы (в кэш попадут локальные/второстепенные переменные). Результата лучшего, чем последовательно пройтись по массиву у Вас не будет.